# How should to-be-published articles be referenced?

Tags: publications, citations

Can I use an unpublished but about to be published soon paper as a reference for a conference paper? 
Suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: about to be published here means already accepted in the conference but not yet published because it gets published few months after the conference..

Comment: For the conference paper, are we talking about the submission version, or about the camera-ready version? Answers will be different depending on which one you mean.

Comment: we are talking about camera ready version

Answer (score 6):

The usual way of handling this situation is to use *[in press]* in the reference instead of the publication date to indicate that the publication is accepted but not yet available. Usually you should also provide soft copies of the to-be-published articles so that the reviewers can have access to them during the review process.

Note that some journals (there is no conference publishing in my field) will postpone the publication of your article until all *in press* articles are online/published to make sure the references don't need further editing and are correct and useful on the long haul.

Note: **Do not** use *in press* if you only speculate that the cited paper will be accepted, only after a firm notification of acceptance.

Comment: I doubt any conference will (or can) postpone publication of their proceedings in the described way. Note that the final version of the proceedings is often handed out digitally, or even printed, to participants at the first day of the conference.

Comment: Some conferences do...i have to submit the camera ready paper after the conference

Comment: Also the online version is not available after some months...i guess a reviewer wants the online version..

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I guess journals have a more archival vocation than conference proceedings that aim at disseminating new material quickly.

Comment: @jpara good point, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @jpara: Fair enough, conferences are certainly organized in different ways across fields. As for "some months", the online version is rarely available before a few months have passed after the conference even on all the conferences I have been to (that would distribute all camera-ready versions on CDs/DVDs during the conference). I suppose the proceedings are caught in some administrative limbo for a while before they get publicly accessible.